# Properly configure scripts with Angular-CLI

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

Let's say I have a project which uses these JS libraries:

- `main.js` which has to be loaded in all pages
- `joe.js` which is a npm package to be loaded in all pages
- `bob.js` which is an old-style 3rd party JS library with no module defined to be loaded in all pages
- `max.js` which is a CommonJS library to be loaded on-demand in some components

So far, I succeded in:

- including `main.js` in the `scripts` property of `angular-cli.json`
- the same as above for `joe.js` using relative paths (`../node_modules/joe/dist/joe.js`)

so they end up in the generated bundle that is loaded on every page.

I had instead a lot of problems with the other two. So far I've managed to include `bob.js` in the bundle by wrapping it in a self-executing function:

```
(function() {
    // old code of bob.js
 })();
```

but **why?** 
And I'm totally clueless on how to include/bundle `max.js`...

Answer (score 0):

For `main, joe and bob.js` you should do this:

To have the scripts available everywhere you can use the `src/assets` folder in your angular-cli folder structure.

And then include your scripts with:

```
<script src="assets/my-script.js"></script>
```

As an option you can get those dependencies from `node_modules` to `src/assets` with a webpack.

**For most cases using CDN is better option than all this.**

---

As for `max.js` you i would create a service to conveniently inject it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MaxService {

 lib: any;
 constructor(){
  this.lib = require('max.js');
 }

}
```

Comment: Maybe I got it wrong or I was not clear about it, but in `/assets/` they are not bundled but copied "as is" which is not my intent (I'd like them all bundled and minified). With `angular-cli.json` anyway I managed somehow to bundle them together, so it's okay (besides, I use cdn's when possible, but I need also to understand the mechanics).
Interesting the service bit about `max.js`, which seems to be my missing piece. Thanks, I'll try and let you know!

Comment: In your situation i would npm install the libraries, minify them directly from node/modules and move them with webpack to src/assets and include them from there as i explained. If you feel my asnwer helped you please upvote.

Comment: as I stated (and tagged) I am working with Angular-CLI, I cannot configure or use webpack directly by any means except for what the tool exposes, which is not much.
I am *not* using webpack per-se.

Comment: Yes you can use webpack. Create a npm command that calls webpack yourself and use it as "prebuild".